# SFTP Mule Client Java API - User Login Time out Issue

Tags: java, mule, sftp

I am working on a Java code to SFTP file to remote from HDFS filesystem. It works fine for smallers file less than 200 MB. For large files I get the following error.

```
     17/08/08 02:44:49 ERROR sftp.SftpClient: Error writing data over SFTP   service, error was: Failure
4: Failure
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2289)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.checkStatus(ChannelSftp.java:1937)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:541)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:439)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:406)
```

My code is as follows:

```
            public static void sendFile(String targetDirectory, String   sourceFileWithFullPath) throws IOException {
    SftpClient client = new SftpClient("karthick");
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    FSDataInputStream fsdisPath = null;
    String filePath = null;
    try {

        filePath=sourceFileWithFullPath;
        Path inputPath = new Path(filePath);
        fsdisPath = fs.open(inputPath);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fsdisPath);
        client.login("karthick","/karthick/id_rsa", null);
        client.changeWorkingDirectory(targetDirectory);
        client.storeFile(inputPath.getName(), bis);
        System.out.println("The actual path is" + client.getAbsolutePath(sourceFileWithFullPath));

    }
    finally {
        if (client != null) {
            client.disconnect();
        }
        if (bis != null) {
            bis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I ensured that I have enough disk space, no memory issues and all the required permissions. What could be other possible ways to avoid this issue. I am planning to have this utility to copy 500GB files. I am beginning java and learning the fundamentals now. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I am receiving this error as well com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: verify: false . I have added keys wherever necessary. How do I resolve this issue

```
    ERROR sftp.SftpClient: Error during login to karthick@karthick
    com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: verify: false
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:295)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:150)
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient.login(SftpClient.java:178)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of 4 reasons:

1)Permissions on the folder you're writing to

2)Spaces on the file path (or name).

3)Wrong slash in the file path.

4)Time out issues are happen while reading or writing the huge File..

Comment: I am geting the user time out session as I have updated the content of the  my question and How do I fix it .

Comment: pls check the jsch 0.1.50 fixes this problem.

The jsch  download page for - http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: I used the jsch 0.1.50 lib.. I am getting the following exception. Is it related to version                                                                                                                     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: identities
      at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:39)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)